# Indexing table columns

Tags: mysql, indexing, xampp, innodb

I am developing an application and I create query strings from the program and pass it to a stored procedure which includes four `Prepared statements`. After passing the variables, the statements would be as follows,

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_correlatedData;

CREATE TABLE tbl_correlatedData 
SELECT t0.*,t1.counttimeStamplocalIp,t2.countlocalPort,t3.countlocalGeo,t4.countisp,t5.countforeignip,t6.countforeignPort,t7.countforeignGeo,t8.countinfection 
FROM tbl_union_threats t0 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tsli t1 
USING (timeStamp,localIp) LEFT JOIN tbl_tslilp t2 USING (timeStamp,localIp,localPort) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tslilplg t3 
USING (timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tslilplgisp t4 
USING (timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tslilplgispfi t5 
USING (timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignip) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tslilplgispfifp t6 
USING (timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignip,foreignPort) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tslilplgispfifpfg t7 
USING (timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignip,foreignPort,foreignGeo) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_tslilplgispfifpfginf t8 USING (timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignip,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection)
GROUP BY timeStamp,localIp;

ALTER TABLE tbl_correlatedData 
MODIFY timeStamp VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY localIp VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY localPort VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY localGeo VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY isp VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY foreignip VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY foreignPort VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY foreignGeo VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
MODIFY infection VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL;

CREATE INDEX id_index ON tbl_correlatedData (timeStamp,localIp,localPort,localGeo,isp,foreignIp,foreignPort,foreignGeo,infection);
```

BUT when the process gets to the indexing query, it gives out an error saying,

`Incorrect key file for table 'tbl_correlateddata'; try to repair it`

**FYI :**
I am trying this out on Windows Vista 32 bit with a free space of 19 GB on the drive with the xampp server and the table getting created shows its size as 25Mb on phpMyadmin.

**EDIT:**
when i try to repair it using `REPAIR TABLE tbl_correlateddata` gives out the following,

```
Table                                |  Op    | Msg_type |  Msg_text
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
db_threatanalysis.tbl_correlateddata |  repair| Error    |  Table 'db_threatanalysis.tbl_correlateddata' doesn...
db_threatanalysis.tbl_correlateddata |  repair| status   |  Operation failed
```

Thank you very much for the help..in advance :)

Comment: Did you try to follow its advice? That is, literally run command: `REPAIR TABLE tbl_correlateddata` ?

Comment: @mvp the repair fails because i am using `innodb` i think :) i tried it..forgot to mention..i edited the question :) thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create compound (multi-column) index, which is just too long for Innodb.

You have 9 columns, each VARCHAR(200), so total index width is 1800 chars. According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html), Innodb key is limited at 3072 chars. So, you should be ok, but, there is no guarantee that `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY ...` was able to reduce all column widths to 200 or less, so even if one remained at something like 4000 chars, you will get this error.

**Solution:**

Reduce number of fields in your compound index.
Analyze queries which are going to query this generated table, and only create indexes that are really necessary. I would imagine most of them will be one-column indexes.

Also, it is rather strange why do you need VARCHAR(200) to store something as simple as timestamp, ip, port, etc. You can probably easily squeeze it to 10 bytes or less and call it a day.

Comment: thank you for the valuable information..i will try this, the issue is, all those alter conditions are generated via serverside code, the code was getting pretty long and i thot of having a fixed `VARCHAR` length of 200 :P .. i will check this n reply back :) thanks again :)

Comment: both your answers are correct..but i have to mark the other 1 as correct because he was first to post it..i really wish i could mark both of these answers :) thank you for the help..the key size was the issue :)

Comment: in that case you should check timestamps

Comment: ohh sorry :P i only saw the edited timestamp..sorry for the confusion...answer marked correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

Your key size might be too long. I tried something similiar on my local MySQL install. Since I dont have your tables I could not run the CREATE TABLE statement. As my database is setup for UNICODE my keys size was over 4000 bytes. MySQL InnoDB can only create indexes with a key size of 3072 bytes.

My code looked like follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_correlatedData 
(
  `timeStamp` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   localIp VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   localPort VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   localGeo VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   isp VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   foreignip VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   foreignPort VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   foreignGeo VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
   infection VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
  );

CREATE INDEX id_index ON tbl_correlatedData
       (timeStamp,
        localIp,
        localPort,
        localGeo,
        isp,
        foreignIp,
        foreignPort,
        foreignGeo,
        infection
 );
```

This resulted in the error:

```
Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes
```

Please read about size limitations here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html. I suspect you have this problem.

Comment: ohh thank you for the answer..i will look into this and post back :)

Comment: I have made a mistake..since both the answers are correct had to give priority to the first to answer :) ... really appreciate your help thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

index key prefixes can be up to 767 bytes for innodb table where it will be approximately 1000 bytes for myisam table

total index length of mysql innodb is 3072

here first you just check the length of the index and if possible reduce the column size varchar(100) for all

if possible create separate indexes ( if it suits your requirement )

see the link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//create-index.html

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6604